# how to use array_search to look for NULL instead of a value

Tags: php

I get from a query a list of records where some of them or all can have NULL values.
Sample data:

| ID | All | Name | Surname |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 4 | John | Smith |
| 34 | 4 | Mike | Reed |
| NULL | 4 | NULL | NULL |
| NULL | 4 | NULL | NULL |

So in this case the array will contain 4 elements and the third one is the first with NULL value for ID.
So I am looking for a way in PHP to determine the first NULL Id (so this will return 3).
Edge cases are with all NULL (should return 1) or no NULL (should return 0)

I was looking for [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) but what I don't get is how to search for NULL instead of a value...

Comment: What have you tried? What does your array look like?  The `ID` col is presumably not the key, since the 2x NULLs would overwrite each other, so how have you structured it?  If you are retrieving records from the DB, are you iterating over those rows to generate the array? If so, you already know which was the first NULL ...?

Comment: the array as I said is coming from a db query (a recursive query actually), so it has column names as keys as you presumably know. I don't manipulate it, neither iterate it. I just look for the first value where ID is null beacuse the query will always return as many rows as the All field value even if there is not a corresponding value. As I wrote I tried to apply arraY_search but with no luck (i was not using it togheter with array_column as the accepted answer) as I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wilmanicesir's answer will be more flexible if you need more comparison options, but another way using `array_search` would be like this:

```php
$nullIdIndex = array_search(null, array_column($data, 'ID'));
```

Though, note PHP arrays are zero-indexed, so in your sample data this will return `2` not 3, if all are null it will be `0` because that's the first null instance, and if none are null it will return `false`.

Also, [per the comment in the PHP docs explaining this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#120784), be careful that this will return the actual *position* in the array where the null is found; if your data has associated *custom keys*, they will **not** be the value returned by array_search using this method.

Comment: I know about the position thing, actually it is what I am looking for. The array will always have custom keys since they are coming from Mysql

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only have to check on ID this could be a solution:

```
# Filter out persons with an id
$noIds = array_filter($data,
    function ($person) {
        return $person['id'] === NULL;
    }
);

// The first result is also the first find
$firstHit = $noIds[0]
```